# How to delete a sublist of a list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, sublist

all I need is the following

```
deletesub:: [Int]->[Int]->[Int]
```

For example,

```
deletesub [2,1,4] [3,1,32,5,2,43,7,4] = [3,32,5,43,7]
```

I searched using the signature at hoogle but nothing :/

Comment: Also please consider accepting an answer by clicking the tick on the side, in case your problem has been solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I search hoogle for `[Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]`, I get as the 5th result `(\\)`, which is the list difference operator.  If I search for `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`, it's the first result.  Is that what you're looking for?  Keep in mind that `[1, 2, 3, 1] \\ [1, 2] == [3, 1]`, it only removes the first occurrence of each element of the second list from the first list.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
deletesub lst = filter (`notElem` lst)
```